# can't replace string with image in android webview html

Tags: java, android, html

Tiker is a string which have name and value both + and - i want to change that with images...
bt using this on + and - will hide bt image don't show...

so help to find my solution.

```
WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

tiker = tiker.replaceAll("\\+","<img src=drawable\"up.PNG\">");
tiker = tiker.replaceAll("\\-","<img src=drawable\"down.PNG\">");

String summary = "<html><body><MARQUEE>"+tiker+"</MARQUEE></body></html>";
mWebView.loadData(summary, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Comment: Why are your image source are so weird? What is 'drawable"up.PNG"'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access images in 'drawable' directory from a WebView. You must put the images in 'assets' directory and access them with 'file:///android_asset/...'

Comment: so should i create assets folder in res??

Comment: @siten The assets directory is in the root of your project folder. It should be on the same level as the /res/ folder, not inside it.

Comment: i tried that by still image not displayed... bt can i retrieve the images from http??

Comment: Are you sure the HTML itself is correct? Try to set a fixed size and background color to that <img> tag to see if it'll appear as a colored rectangle where you expect it.